# Почему блины печем, а мясо жарим?

Tags: употребление-слов

Почему  блины печем, а мясо жарим. Но и то, и другое на сковородке?

Comment: Может, это заложено в свойствах самого продукта? Мясо вообще можно *печь*, *запекать* где-либо (не обязательно на сковороде)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Антон Павлович Чехов в своём рассказе «Блины» писал: «Вы знаете, что блины живут уже более тысячи лет... Они появились на белый свет раньше русской истории, выдуманы так же, как и самовар, русскими мозгами..." В главном Антон Павлович, безусловно, прав – история происхождения блинов до сих пор покрыта тайной. Ученые кивают то в сторону Китая, то в сторону Египта. И хотя блины в том или ином обличии известны многим народам, классический дрожжевой блин славяне могут с полным правом считать своим национальным достоянием. А предыстория эта к тому, что  выражение "печь блины" появилось с того давнего времени, где *блины готовились только в печи* и обязательно на чугунных сковородках (часто это были несколько сковородочек, спаянных вместе). Так что жарим мы картошку, мясо, грибы и т. д., а блины - печём.

Answer (score 5):

Моя версия такая. Блины - исконное, древнее блюдо. Их пекли в печи. А мясо жарили разве что на открытом огне. Пользоваться сковородой стали относительно недавно. Поэтому блины продолжают *печь* (в память о домашней печи), а мясо стали *жарить*.

Answer (score 3):

Настоящие блины именно пекут. В печи. Или в современных условиях — в духовке. А те, которые, как Вы говорите, на сковородке — те как раз жарятся. "Я сегодня нажарила блинчиков".
Мясо же или, например, яичницу мы готовим на сковородке, на плите.
Вот и вся разница.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ есть у Вильяма Похлебкина.
У меня нет его под рукой (если интересно - найду), поэтому - передаю как запомнил. 
Дело не в сковороде, а в масле.
Жарка (жарение) - процесс кулинарной обработки, при котором масло (жир) играет роль активного термического компонента - через него передаётся жар. 
При выпечке же блинов масло используется исключительно для смазки поверхности - лучшего растекания и борьбы с пригаром. 
У некоторых хозяек, правда масла на сковороде столько, что оно со сковороды и блин пропитывает - но тогда это именно жарка, причем - в слое масла, т.е. пряжение.

Comment: В современных сковородах с антипригарным покрытием вопрос о масле не актуален.

Comment: Тогда и вопрос о жарке или  выпечке неактуален. Без масла - это уже не жарение.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю автора, вопрос не о кулинарных терминах, а об употреблении разных глаголов в обиходе.

Comment: Интересная версия. Про масло - точное замечание. С другой стороны, вроде бы бывает и *жарочный шкаф*?

Comment: >Если я правильно понимаю автора, вопрос не о кулинарных терминах, а об употреблении разных глаголов в обиходе.    
    
Да, но в обиходе-то частенько блины вполне себе жарят. Так что тут и спорить не о чем.  
  
Ну и то, что обычно обиходное употребление идет от профессионального. Насколько помню, жарение как способ кулинарной обработки вообще очень недавнее, для русской кухни нехарактерное. "Жаркое" - это типичное тушение, его бы и надо назвать тушение. Остальное - верченое, печеное, вареное, квашеное - вполне соответствует процессу. Так что все претензии - немцам, от которых пришло жарение

Comment: >С другой стороны, вроде бы бывает и жарочный шкаф?  
  
Это позднейшее изобретение. Я не очень знаком с технологией, но, похоже, процесс не сосвем соответствует названию.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы блины отнесла к выпечке. А поскольку торты, пироги, слойки, ватрушки и другие мучные блюда пекутся, то и блины (несмотря на сковородку) предлагаю печь. А если в блин завернута начинка, то тогда уже обжаривают. Оладья тоже пекут. А вот сырники жарят. На самом деле интересный вопрос!

Comment: >Я бы блины отнесла к выпечке.   
  
Так весь вопрос-то в том, почему.

Comment: Может, все мучное выпекается? Не могу вспомнить что-нибудь мучное жареное.  Ведь и хлеб печется... И пряники...

Comment: Пирожки жареные.
Но вообще наблюдение интересное.

Comment: В пользу ответа о жире и жарке: пончики и беляши (хоть и мучное) жарят.

Answer (score 2):

Заглянем в "Толковый словарь русского языка" С.И. Ожегова (М., 1984).

Жарить. --- 1. Приготовляя (пищу), держать на сильном жару без воды, ТОЛЬКО В СВОЕМ СОКУ и в МАСЛЕ, ЖИРАХ. ЖАРИТЬ котлеты. (С.163) А также: ЖАРИТЬ МЯСО, картошку. яйца...

ПЕЧЬ. ---1.Приготовлять (пищу) СУХИМ (без масла, без жира --- В.А.) нагреванием на жару. ПЕЧЬ пироги (С.445). А также: пирожки, торт, хлеб... 
Ср.: Жарить пирожки (на сковороде, в масле) ---> жареные пирожки --- но: печь пирожки (в духовке, без жира, без масла)---> печёные пирожки.

Что касается БЛИНОВ, то в Словаре находим: Блин. --- Тонкая лепёшка из жидкого теста, ИСПЕЧЕННАЯ на сковороде (С. 46), т.е. приготовленная СУХИМ нагреванием на жару. Позволю себе порассуждать (может быть, и ошибаюсь): наверное, готовили именно ТАК и именно В ПЕЧИ раньше, наши предки, т.е. ПЕКЛИ блины. Так, видимо, и нужно ПЕЧЬ БЛИНЫ, если следовать прежним кулинарным установкам, а потом уже смазывать их поверхность маслом, желательно сливочным. Однако ситуация с течением времени изменилась: современные хозяйки обычно или  добавляют растительное масло в само тесто, или сначала наливают масло на раскаленную сковороду, а потом в него --- жидкое тесто. Фактически теперь (они) ЖАРЯТ БЛИНЫ, но мы продолжаем называть это действие по-старому: (они) ПЕКУТ БЛИНЫ.

Comment: Но вот я когда пеку блины, смазываю чугунную сковороду тонким слоем. Таким же обычно смазывают и противень в духовке.В чем же разница?  Так что объясняется скорее,действительно, историческими причинами. Пекли - в печи...

Comment: Ларf, так противень - это тоже запекание. 
Разница - в количестве масла. Вернее в том, что оно не используется как термический агент.

>наверное, готовили именно ТАК и именно В ПЕЧИ раньше  
  
Правильно рассуждаете. С маленькой оговоркой. На сковородке такое невозможно. На антипригарной ещё получается без смазки, но всё равно - не совсем то. Масло же используется исключительно для смазки и удаления пригара от предыдущего блина, по сути идет именно сухое выпекание. 

Как освобожусь - найду Похлёбкина - дам точные цитаты.